# Can't use Sass functions in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I have the latest sass-rails gem. All of my stylesheets are .scss. I have confirmed that directives such as @extend and @import are working so I have some Sass functionality, but I cannot use every function?

Namely, I would like to use the lighten($color, $amount) function as defined [here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#lighten-instance_method) or even the mix() function, but they are not recognized.
I can use color functions such as hsl() or saturation().

Here is the problem code:

```
.high-emphasis-orange {
   @extend %high-emphasis-shared;
   background-color: $primary-orange;
   border-color: $primary-orange;

   &.hover {
     background-color: saturation($primary-orange);
     border-color: lighten($primary-orange, 20);
   }
}
```

Comment: `&.hover` or `&:hover`?

Comment: It's been on of those days.... staring at a screen too long! That was the issue. Thank you @QuentinVeron!!

Answer (score 0):

The error was a simple syntax issue in my code. The lighten() function works fine.